# How to disable group of text field in cq5 dialog using script

Tags: dialog, aem

I have group of text field in a cq dialog. i want disable without using for loop in js. Is it possible to disable findByType("textfield").disable like this code so that all the text field in that dialog will be disabled

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't work in a single statement, though I am not very sure. However you can use `CQ.Ext.each(findByType("textfield"), function() { this.setDisabled(true); });`

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working

Comment: But it should be like this CQ.Ext.each(dialog.findByType("textfield"), function() { this.setDisabled(true); });

Comment: Yes it should be the same. Since you didnt mention on what you were using the findByType method in your question, I just left it generic. Will add an answer to this with the correct script.

Comment: Thanks a lot...pls add this in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve it in a single statement. However, you can use the  `CQ.Ext.each` to loop over the collection of `textfield` and then disable them.

Assuming you have the handle of the parent container such as `dialog` / `panel` (in this case a `dialog`), the code would be as follows.

```
CQ.Ext.each(dialog.findByType("textfield"), function() { 
    this.setDisabled(true); 
});
```